# Notice: Undefined index - Solving with isset?

Tags: php, magento

```
Notice: Undefined index: extension  in /var/www/.. on line 187

    //185 - $f_name = $this->filename;
    //186 - $path_parts = pathinfo($f_name);
    //187 - $file_ext = $path_parts['extension'];
```

---

After some googleing I've seen alot of Isset being used. But I'm in doubt, about how to use it, in this case? Is it even going to solve the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) in this case. You first check if the key is set before trying to access it. I would use the ternary operator to set a default value if you need to.

```
$file_ext = isset($path_parts['extension']) ? $path_parts['extension'] : null;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since php 7.0, You can use null coalescing operator

```
$file_ext = $path_parts['extension'] ?? null;
```

[https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Answer (score 1):

pathinfo will only return the "extension" index if the path has an extension, otherwise it will not return this index.

A simple check should be used to determine whether the path has an index, such as:

```
if(!empty($path_parts['extension'])) {
  // Extension exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$f_name` has no extension, so `$path_parts['extension']` is not set.

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), look Example #2